# find when two equal numbers are in the same column of two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables made this way:

tb1:

```
  id  f0 | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 | f6 | f7 | f8 | f9 
  ---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
   1   90 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 54 | 85 | 86 | 77 | 88 | 79
   2   80 | 1  | 62 | 63 | 74 | 55 | 6  | 87 | 68 | 49
   ...
   (9 rows)
```

tb2:

```
 id   r0 | r1 | r2 | r3 | r4 | r5 | r6 | r7 | r8 | r9 
---+-----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
 1    70 | 11 | 62 | 3  | 44 | 5  | 56 | 77 | 38 | 9
 2    50 | 81 | 2  | 23 | 14 | 85 | 26 | 87 | 58 | 19
 3    90 | 51 | 82 | 33 | 64 | 25 | 16 | 27 | 48 | 49
 ---
 (9 rows)
```

the result of the expected query is this:

tfr:

```
id   fr11   fr12   fr21   fr13
---+------+------+------+------
0  |  -   |  -   |  -   |  90
1  |  -   |  81  |  -   |  -
2  |  -   |  -   |  62  |  82
3  |  -   |  -   |  -   |  - 
4  |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -
5  |  -   |  85  |  -   |  -
6  |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -
7  |  77  |  -   |  -   |  -
8  |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -
9  |  -   |  -   |  -   |  -
```

starting with the first line that is with tb1.id = 1 and tb2.id = 1 only in column 7 of both tables there are two equal values,
therefore the number 77 will be shown in the fr11 column on line 7, while on the other rows of the same column there will be a dash.

advancing with tb1.id = 1 and tb2.id = 2 in column 1 and 5 of both tables you will find two equal numbers 81 and 85 respectively
which will be shown in column fr12 in the position of row 1 and 5.

again with tb1.id = 2 and tb2.id = 1 there will be a match on column 2 with the number 62 (column f2 row (2) and column r2 row (1)).

same procedure with tb1.id = 1 and tb2.id = 3 the columns f0 row1, r0 row 3 and f2, r2 have the numbers 90 and 82 equal respectively and will be shown in the column fr13.

how can this query be realized?

thanks in advance for the considerations!

Comment: So why are (tab1.id,tab2.id,f/r col): ( 2,2,7) and (2,3,9) excluded from the desired results. BTW what problem are you actually trying to solve, please explain in requirements terms not sql and/or tables.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer .. I did not understand what you mean for (2,2,7) and (2,3,9) ..
if you talk about the number 87 it will be included in the fr22 column, but in the example it has not been reported.
the columns f of the table tb1 will be compared only with the columns r of the table tb2 with the same numbering, only the position of the row (id) changes. so there will never be a column f0 that compares with a r1, r2 .. but only with a column r0 .. etc

Comment: This doesn't feel at all relational in nature. Like it's a REALLY bad fit for SQL.